# Trusted server certificate issued by unknown name even though I have all chain as trusted

Tags: tls, windows-10

I'm receiving "Valid certificate: The connection to this site is using a valid, trusted server certificate issued by unknown name." (err_tunnel_connection_failed)

I don't understand the error. I'm using windows 10 and chrome. I have added all the certificates in the chain CA1 > CA3 > sso to the local computer via Certificate Management tool.

CA1 is under Trusted root certification authorities. CA3 IS under Intermediate certification authorities. sso is under Trusted Publishers and Trusted people.

If I double click the sso certificate and look under certification path all looks good ok.

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: It seems a windows store issue but can't work it out.  I used the same certificates via wget after converting the certifcates from cer format to pem. and I get 200 ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted! it was a proxy issue.  I didn't realize I was being blocked by a proxy until I checked with Wireshark.  Certificates were ok all along.

The proxy was blocking name resolution.   This was misleading as I was able to ping and resovle dns via the command line.